RevenueCat Paywall Component Causing Crash on Android Device - NoSuchMethodError in AnimatedContent Method
I'm encountering a crash on Android when trying to display the RevenueCat paywall component in my React Native app. The same component works fine on iOS, but on Android, the app crashes with the following error:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method AnimatedContent(Ljava/lang/Object;Landroidx/compose/ui/Modifier;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Landroidx/compose/ui/Alignment;Ljava/lang/String;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function4;Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;II)V in class Landroidx/compose/animation/AnimatedContentKt; or its super classes

and the whole error is:
                                                                                                    Process: com.community_react_native, PID: 4388
                                                                                                    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method AnimatedContent(Ljava/lang/Object;Landroidx/compose/ui/Modifier;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Landroidx/compose/ui/Alignment;Ljava/lang/String;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function4;Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;II)V in class Landroidx/compose/animation/AnimatedContentKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt' appears in /data/app/~~lGvRWF9YKKIqoF12Gr8hVA==/com.community_react_native-VSG9A0ZZJCTHWCqmjGZLJg==/base.apk)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.templates.Template7Kt.Features(Template7.kt:370)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.templates.Template7Kt.Template7PortraitContent(Template7.kt:216)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.templates.Template7Kt.Template7(Template7.kt:131)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.InternalPaywallKt.TemplatePaywall(InternalPaywall.kt:167)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.InternalPaywallKt.access$TemplatePaywall(InternalPaywall.kt:1)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.InternalPaywallKt$LoadedPaywall$3$1.invoke(InternalPaywall.kt:148)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.InternalPaywallKt$LoadedPaywall$3$1.invoke(InternalPaywall.kt:147)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.InternalPaywallKt.LoadedPaywall(InternalPaywall.kt:143)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.InternalPaywallKt.access$LoadedPaywall(InternalPaywall.kt:1)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.InternalPaywallKt$InternalPaywall$2$2.invoke(InternalPaywall.kt:88)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.InternalPaywallKt$InternalPaywall$2$2.invoke(InternalPaywall.kt:86)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:118)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibilityKt.AnimatedEnterExitImpl(AnimatedVisibility.kt:818)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibilityKt.AnimatedVisibilityImpl(AnimatedVisibility.kt:741)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibilityKt.AnimatedVisibility(AnimatedVisibility.kt:135)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.InternalPaywallKt$InternalPaywall$2.invoke(InternalPaywall.kt:82)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.InternalPaywallKt$InternalPaywall$2.invoke(InternalPaywall.kt:64)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.fonts.PaywallThemeKt.PaywallTheme(PaywallTheme.kt:13)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.InternalPaywallKt.InternalPaywall(InternalPaywall.kt:64)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.PaywallKt.Paywall(Paywall.kt:11)
                                                                                                        at com.revenuecat.purchases.ui.revenuecatui.views.PaywallView.Content(PaywallView.kt:151)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:252)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:251)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:186)
2024-08-14 13:16:08.291  4388-4388  AndroidRuntime          com.community_react_native           E      at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:119)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:118)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:110)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:139)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$2.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:248)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:123)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:90)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3302)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3235)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:725)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:1071)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeInitial(Composition.kt:633)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:619)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:123)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:114)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1289)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:114)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:164)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.kt:314)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.kt:192)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:121)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:114)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1364)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:21442)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3532)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3539)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5344)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5130)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.addView(ReactViewGroup.java:543)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5070)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactClippingViewManager.addView(ReactClippingViewManager.java:40)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactClippingViewManager.addView(ReactClippingViewManager.java:20)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.manageChildren(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:533)
2024-08-14 13:16:08.291  4388-4388  AndroidRuntime          com.community_react_native           E      at com.swmansion.reanimated.layoutReanimation.ReanimatedNativeHierarchyManager.manageChildren(ReanimatedNativeHierarchyManager.java:337)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$ManageChildrenOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:183)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run(UIViewOperationQueue.java:910)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.flushPendingBatches(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1023)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.-$$Nest$mflushPendingBatches(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1083)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:29)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$1.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:89)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1493)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1503)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1118)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:1027)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1471)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8395)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)
2024-08-14 13:16:08.293  4388-4388  OOMEventManagerFK       com.community_react_native           W  Failed to mkdir /data/miuilog/stability/memleak/heapdump/
2024-08-14 13:16:08.290  4388-4388  ty_react_native         com.community_react_native           W  type=1400 audit(0.0:104469): avc: denied { search } for name="miuilog" dev="dm-45" ino=584 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c178,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:data_log_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=com.community_react_native
2024-08-14 13:16:08.290  4388-4388  ty_react_native         com.community_react_native           W  type=1400 audit(0.0:104470): avc: denied { search } for name="miuilog" dev="dm-45" ino=584 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c178,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:data_log_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=com.community_react_native
2024-08-14 13:16:08.290  4388-4388  ty_react_native         com.community_react_native           W  type=1400 audit(0.0:104471): avc: denied { search } for name="miuilog" dev="dm-45" ino=584 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c178,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:data_log_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=com.community_react_native
2024-08-14 13:16:08.290  4388-4388  ty_react_native         com.community_react_native           W  type=1400 audit(0.0:104472): avc: denied { search } for name="miuilog" dev="dm-45" ino=584 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c178,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:data_log_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=com.community_react_native
2024-08-14 13:16:08.290  4388-4388  ty_react_native         com.community_react_native           W  type=1400 audit(0.0:104473): avc: denied { search } for name="miuilog" dev="dm-45" ino=584 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c178,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:data_log_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=com.community_react_native
2024-08-14 13:16:08.326  4388-4388  Process                 com.community_react_native           I  Process is going to kill itself!
                                                                                                    java.lang.Exception
                                                                                                        at android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:1344)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$KillApplicationHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:181)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1073)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:2306)
2024-08-14 13:16:08.326  4388-4388  Process                 com.community_react_native           I  Sending signal. PID: 4388 SIG: 9


Steps to Reproduce:
Implement the RevenueCat paywall component in the app.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { View, ActivityIndicator, Text } from 'react-native';

import Purchases from 'react-native-purchases';

import RevenueCatUI from 'react-native-purchases-ui';

const PayWallScreen = ({ navigation, route, setLoading }) => {

  const [offerings, setOfferings] = useState(null);

  const [loading, setLoadingState] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {

    navigation.setOptions({ headerShown: true });

    const fetchOfferings = async () => {

      try {

        const fetchedOfferings = await Purchases.getOfferings();

        if (fetchedOfferings.current !== null) {

          setOfferings(fetchedOfferings.current);

        } else {

          console.log("No offerings found");

        }

      } catch (e) {

        console.error("Error fetching offerings:", e);

      } finally {

        setLoadingState(false);

        setLoading(false);

      }

    };

    fetchOfferings();

  }, []);

  if (loading) {

    return <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />;

  }

  return (

    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

      {offerings ? (

        <RevenueCatUI.Paywall />

      ) : (

        <View>

          <Text>No offerings available</Text>

        </View>

      )}

    </View>

  );

};

export default PayWallScreen;

Run the app on an Android device.
Navigate to the screen where the paywall is supposed to be displayed.
The app crashes as soon as the paywall
<RevenueCatUI.Paywall /> 
is rendered.
What I Have Tried:

Added the necessary ProGuard rules for Jetpack Compose and RevenueCat as recommended in the documentation.
Verified that the RevenueCat SDK is correctly configured and later offering shows on console log.
Cleaned and rebuilt the project multiple times.
enabled billing in AndroidManifest

What I Expected
to see the revenuecat paywall component display as is shown in my ios device
Additional Notes:
I've searched the community and StackOverflow for similar issues, but the solutions provided (e.g., adding ProGuard rules, avoiding modals) have not resolved the issue.
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to fix this crash.
SDK and Versions:
React Native: 0.74.0
"react-native-purchases": "^8.0.1",
"react-native-purchases-ui": "^8.0.0",
